# View Filter based on condition

Tags: 7, views

I have a View that is using the Table format to show all users who have uploaded content under a particular node. This view will be visible to anyone in the *Authenticated User* role. Users in *Administrator* role (about 4 users) also contribute to this, but I don't want their details to be visible to anyone else in the table. This is **not** intended to be an exposed filter.

So basically, if the current logged in user is in the *Authenticated User* role, then he should not see the admins.

If the current logged in user is in the *Administrator* role, then he should see everyone.

Possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the sounds of it, you're looking for [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module:

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> ```
>  Equal To
>  Not Equal To
>  Greater Than
>  Less Than
>  Empty
>  Not Empty
> ```
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the condition.

Comment: Hi Geoff. Thanks! I've used Views Conditional on previous projects, and my experience with it is that it works more on individual Fields. I need rather to filter out a complete row in a table (comprised of fields)

Comment: ahh, I see.  one alternative is to clone the view, making one accessible to Admins and the other to authenticated users, then you can choose what elements are displayed and in what format for each role

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought of doing actually. trying to avoid that as I'm sure there must be a way to accomplish this.

Comment: my only other suggestion would be to use a views preprocessor and filter the values manually by code based on the current uID...